# Ruby inheritance and require order

Tags: ruby, inheritance, sinatra

I am trying to set up a new modularised Sinatra app. This is the relevant folder structure:

```
- app 
  - controllers
    - application_controller.rb
    - website_controller.rb
  - config.ru
```

The `application_controller.rb` defines the `ApplicationController` class, requires `sinatra/base` and, apart from that, doesn't do anything interesting.

The `website_controller.rb` inherits `application_controller.rb`:

```
# website_controller.rb
class WebsiteController < ApplicationController

  include Sinatra::Cookies
  ...
end
```

My `config.ru` file is what I run to start the Sinatra app, so it is supposed to require all the classes:

```
#config.ru
require 'sinatra/base'

Dir.glob('./app/{models,helpers,controllers}/*.rb').each {|file|
  require file
}

...
```

When it requires all files, it requires `website_controller.rb` before requiring `application_controller.rb`. That way, when the inheritance on `WebsiteController` is parsed, it does not know yet what `ApplicationController` is, and I get the error `uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)`.

What is the best practice to set up my project so I have all required files ready without facing this kind of ordering problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of `website_controller.rb`, require `application_controller.rb`.

You may feel it redundant, but that won't harm. This is the most robust way.

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid. Isn't there a way to "lazily" require my files so I don't have to manage them on a file basis?

Comment: You either control the order of requiring the files in `config.ru`, or do as I wrote above.

Comment: @Matheus208 `require` and `require_relative` *are* lazy (in that they only load once) but it is good practice to add requires for each file that needs something - do you not run tests? Do you need to load your entire app just to test one file? Loading files from the config.ru *and* individual requires in each file is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

So, the other answer is actually the correct and easiest way - but if for whatever reason you don't want to do it that way, you can use `autoload` provided you've developed your Sinatra app in the "modular" style.

In `config.ru` you are currently "eager-loading" all of your files.  Instead, you would explicitly list the load paths for unknown constants - like so:

```
autoload :ApplicationController, 'app/controllers/application_controller'
autoload :WebsiteController, 'app/controllers/website_controller'
```

Note that `autoload` is a method on `Module` so you have to put the calls to `autoload` within the same 'namespace' - ie:

```
module MyApp
  autoload :MyThing, 'models/my_thing'
end
```

Will fire the autoload when the constant `MyApp::MyThing` is missing. That said - unless you *know why* you need to autoload your classes, just require it at the top of the file.